# Safecracker Registration - Entry Ids are all 0

Tags: safecracker, safecracker-registration

I have this code in safecracker registration form

```
<select required name="gender" data-content="{instructions:gender}" data-title="Help" data-placement="right" data-trigger="focus" id="gender">
    <option value=""></option>
    {exp:channel:entries channel="genders" disable="categories|category_fields|member_data|pagination" orderby="entry_id" sort="asc" dynamic="no"}
        <option value="{entry_id}">{gender_name}</option>
    {/exp:channel:entries}
</select>
```

When I first load the page, it outputs correct entry_ids for the gender.

The problem arises when I try to submit a form that causes an error. I get redirected to the same page but the difference is that in the field above, ALL entry_ids are 0.

```
<select required name="gender" data-content="{instructions:gender}" data-title="Help" data-placement="right" data-trigger="focus" id="gender">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="0">Male</option>
    <option value="0">Female</option>
</select>
```

Any idea why this is the case?

EDIT: I forgot to say that this code is in a Snippet. It probably is relevant to the discussion.

Answer (score 1):

My guess this is an EE parse order issue. Assuming you are registering for a new member, the default entry_id is obviously 0 since there is no entry yet. Safecracker is actually parsing the entry_id incorrectly before your entries loop runs. This should have nothing to do with Safecracker Registration, as the same thing would happen with a regular SC form too.

You have two options:

1) Use my Entries addon and prefix your nested tag so there is no parsing conflict. Entries is stable, I just haven't actually released it yet.

https://objectivehtml.com/entries

2) Use Stash to parse that entries loop outside of the Safecracker tag.

Let me know if you have any more questions.

Comment: The code is in a snippet btw.